Did the Kalasha of Amrta held by Dhanvantari basically contain Soma?
In the Rg-Veda, only the concept of Soma existed, with "amrta" being an adjective/epithet of the Soma drink.
I wonder, when Dhanvantari rose from the ocean of milk, was the amrta basically Soma, or was it a completely different liquid?
If it is a different liquid, what are the physical qualities associated with it? what is its color and smell? is it also intoxicating like Soma?
Overall, is Hindu mythology consistent with the idea that Soma = Amrta, or they are in fact two different divine drinks in non-vedic scripture ?

In the Rigveda Amrita is one of the synonyms of Soma or Somaras. However, the two don't need to be the same necessarily. It depends on what context it is used, there is a very elaborate ritualised process to make Soma which is done in Somayagya by chanting some special mantras and pressing the Somalata plant. This soma drink is considered to increase longevity and therefore also named as Amrita or nectar of immortality however the Amrita that the devas drank was not somaras AFAIK because to get Somaras you have to go through Somyagya.

thanks, so I thought. regardless of the question, I really don't think Somalata is the original plant used for soma :)

Yes, Soma and Amrita both are same.
Rig Veda 8.48.3.:

अपाम सोमममृता अभूमागन्म ज्योतिरविदाम देवान् । किं नूनमस्मान्कृणवदरातिः किमु धूर्तिरमृत मर्त्यस्य ॥
apāma somam amṛtā abhūmāganma jyotir avidāma devān | kiṃ nūnam asmān kṛṇavad arātiḥ kim u dhūrtir amṛta martyasya ||
“We have drunk Soma and become immortal; we have attained the light (of heaven), the Gods discovered. Now what may foeman's malice do to harm us? What, O Immortal, mortal man's deception?”

This Soma is none other than the Moon itself.
Shatapatha Brahmana Section 1.6.4.5.:

The gods said, 'Nothing but Soma will satiate him: let us prepare Soma for him!' They prepared Soma for him. Now this king Soma, the food of the gods, is no other than the moon.

Don't see everything in a literal sense, they are mostly philosophical related to Yoga.
Yoga-Kundalini Upanishad.:

67-69. (Kundalini) Pierces the Brahmagranthi formed of rajas and flashes at once like lightning at the mouth of Susumna. Then it goes up at once through Vishnugranthi to the heart. Then it goes up through Rudragranthi and above it to the middle of the eyebrows; having pierced this place (Ajna Chakra), it goes up to the Mandala (sphere) of the moon (Indu Chakra). It dries up the moisture (amrita/soma) produced by the moon in the Anahata (Indu/Moon) Chakra having sixteen petals.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..
